# Azure Virtual Machine Extension fileUris path with Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure

Need to implement VM extension, using Terraform and Azure DevOps.I am trying to pass fileUris value from .tfvars or create Dynamically from storage account details ["https://${var.Storageaccountname}.blob.core.windows.net/${var.containername}/test.sh"], Both the scenarios are not working.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "main" {
  name                 = "${var.vm_name}"
  location           ="${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "fileUris" :"${var.fileUris}",
    "commandToExecute": "sh <name of file> --ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted\""
  }
  SETTINGS
}
```

Any tips on fixing this issue? Maybe some other solution to achieve zero hardcoding in main.tf/variable.tf?

Comment: What's the error message? Is it a Linux or Windows VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to this working sample to deploy the extension on Linux VM. The script file stored a Storage account.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                       = "test-LinuxExtension"
  virtual_machine_id         =  "/subscriptions/xxx/virtualMachines/www"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                       = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version       = "2.1"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true


  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
            "commandToExecute": "sh aptupdate.sh",
            "storageAccountName": "xxxxx",
            "storageAccountKey": "xxxxx",
            "fileUris": [
                "${var.fileUris}"
            ]
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply.Let me try this @Nancy Xiong

Answer (score 0):

If we store the script in Azure blob storage, we need to provide storage key then the extension can have permission  to access the script. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux).   Please add the following setting in your script

```
...
protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      
      "storageAccountName": "mystorageaccountname",
      "storageAccountKey": "myStorageAccountKey"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
...
```

Comment: yes  resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "VmExtension_nat" {
  name                 = "CustomScriptExt2"
  virtual_machine_id   = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.NatVM.id}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
        "storageAccountName": "${var.snx_scriptstorageaccount}",
        "storageAccountKey": "${var.StorageKey1}",
        "fileUris":[<file_uris>],
        "commandToExecute": "sh ./test.sh"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}

Comment: @RoopaK Sorry I cannot understand. COuld you please describe it in detail?